# Why $M = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \vert x^3+y^3 = 0\}$ seems not to be a manifold for $(x,y) = (0,0)$?

Tags: manifolds

Mathematically this can't be counted as manifold because $\textbf{rank}D_f(0,0) = (3\cdot 0^2\quad 3\cdot0^2) = 0$.

However, I see no problem at this point the reason being the manifold is a straight line $(y = -x)$

Comment: What is $f$? And why “Mathematically”? Are you suggesting that, say, from the point of view of Physics it *is* a manifold?

Comment: You probably know a criterion for a level curve to be a manifold?

Comment: $M$ is a manifold (indeed, this is a straight line). However, you are right, the map $(x,y) \mapsto x^3 + y^{3}$ is not a submersion at $0$. The thing is that, if you can write $M = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \psi(x,y) = 0\}$, then if $0$ is a regular value of $\psi$ it follows that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, it is not true that if $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ then $0$ must be a regular value of $\psi$ (you have a counter-example).